# Cómo ordenar un array por cadena

Tags: javascript, array

Encontré este código que ordena elementos numéricos de un array dependiendo de cual es el número más grande, con javascript

```
var arr = [ 40, 1, 5, 200 ];
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b;});  // [ 1, 5, 40, 200 ]
```

Lo que necesito es eso mismo pero con cadenas, tengo un `array` que contiene preguntas enumeradas dentro de la  misma cadena es decir

```
var preguntas = [{
    pregunta:"1 Primera Pregunta",
    respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 1"
},{
   pregunta:"22 Una pregunta de Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 2"
},{
   pregunta: 3" tercera Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 3"
}]
```

al usar `sort()` los ordena según su valor `unicode` `1,22,3` y necesito ordenarlas así `1,3,22`

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede recurrir al método [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/localeCompare) con algunas opciones definidas entre los parámetros para que evalué correctamente los números y letras inmersos en las cadenas.

Está claro que deberá acceder a su propiedad pregunta en cada item del array.

El primer parámetro del método es `locale`, para este caso `en` de inglés británico, algunas otras opciones las puede [encontrar aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation)

El segundo parámetro es un objeto de opciones, para este caso le decimos quese debe utilizar la intercalación numérica, de modo que `"1" <"2" <"10"`. el valor por defecto es false.

```js
var preguntas = [{
    pregunta:"1 Primera Pregunta",
    respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 1"
},{
   pregunta:"22 Una pregunta de Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 22"
},{
   pregunta: "3 tercera Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 3"
},
{
   pregunta: "2 segunda Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 3"
}]

preguntas.sort((a, b) =>
  a.pregunta.localeCompare(b.pregunta, 'en', { numeric: true }));
console.log(preguntas);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal sería que el modelo de tus datos tuviera una propiedad numérica con el número de la pregunta:

```
{
  numero: 1,
  pregunta: '¿Cómo estás?',
  respuesta: 'Bien'
}
```

Ya que de esta manera sería mucho más simple el método de ordenamiento utilizando algo como:

```
preguntas.sort( (a, b) => {
  return a.numero > b.numero;
});
```

Pero como tienes que ordenarlo con una string podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
let preguntas = [
  {
      pregunta:"1 Primera Pregunta",
      respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 1"
  },
  {
     pregunta:"22 Una pregunta de Pregunta",
     respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 2"
  },
  {
     pregunta: "3 tercera Pregunta",
     respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 3"
  }
];
preguntas.sort( (a, b) => {
  let izq = parseInt(a.pregunta.substr(0,a.pregunta.indexOf(' ')));
  let der = parseInt(b.pregunta.substr(0,b.pregunta.indexOf(' ')));
  if ( izq < der ) {
    return -1;
  } else if ( izq > der ) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
console.log(preguntas);
// 1 Primera... , 3 tercera... , 22 una pregunta....
```

Por cada cadena de texto almacenada en `pregunta` se obtiene desde el caracter 0 hasta el primer espacio, lo cual es un número. Ese número sigue estando en una cadena de texto, por lo que se utiliza `parseInt` para convertirlo a su tipo numérico.

Aquí el método sort devuelve varios números para poder realizar correctamente el ordenamiento, [tal como lo indica MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort).

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta la encontre en stackOverflow en ingles

```
var preguntas = [{
    pregunta:"1 Primera Pregunta",
    respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 1"
},{
   pregunta:"22 Una pregunta de Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 2"
},{
   pregunta: "3 tercera Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 3"
}];
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
sorted=sortByKey(preguntas,"pregunta");
console.log(preguntas,sorted);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key-with-date-value

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera agregar una explicación de lo que realiza en el código para que sea de mejor ayuda, revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes es un Arreglo de Objetos y debido a esto cambia un poco tu **JavaScript**

```js
var preguntas = [{
    pregunta:"1 Primera Pregunta",
    respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 1"
},{
   pregunta:"22 Una pregunta de Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 2"
},{
   pregunta: "3 tercera Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 3"
},{
   pregunta: "0 tercera Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 3"
},{
   pregunta: "10 tercera Pregunta",
   respuesta:"respuesta a pregunta 3"
}]
preguntas.sort(
function(a,b){ 
    return a.pregunta > (b.pregunta) 
    }
); 
console.log(preguntas)
```

El orden que te muestra es por Cadena de Texto y no numerico, si quieres hacerlo numerico lo ideal es que tenga el numero de la pregunta afuera para poder recorrerlo